Recent Movie on Arthurian Legend
I watched a movie about a year ago that I believe was a recent release then. It was based on the Arthurian legend, Excalibur, etc. The movie was probably a B movie of some kind.
I remember a few things about the movie, I am trying to find the name.
The main story takes place in a castle prison from which our hero (Arthur) is trying to escape and he needs to defeat three trials. One of which is a giant man.
There is a scene at the start with some Roman soldiers who are cursed by a Druid woman.
There is a scene where they are in France or Italy or some unnamed European town and they are having a party when guards come and take the hero to prison. In this party someone throws a dagger into someones butt, and someone is trying to force himself on a girl - no one seems to care about either of these things.

This isn't Arthur but rather Richard I. You seem to be talking about the 2013 film Richard The Lionheart in which Richard's father (Malclom McDowell) tests his son's loyalty by sending him to prison where he must face 3 trials (one of which is a giant knight). There's also a drunken feast in the beginning in which people are making out and a dagger is thrown into a guy's butt but no one really cares (including the guy himself who just keeps drinking). Here's the trailer:




I just love the first few seconds where Richard is shown running, then leaping and running on a wall to change direction (sideways), parkour style.... like a knight in armor could EVER do that. Like a knight, in no armor at all, wearing shoes of the time, could do that.

This may come as a shock, but the movie is... not great. ;)
